# Is there a way to convert a large wordlist into each word on a new line

Tags: excel, cpu-word, word-list

I have a word list for example:
Jacob Matt Ben Don

I want to make them like this.

> Jacob
>
> Matt
>
> Ben
>
> Don

Anyone know how?

Comment: Are you writing code? What language? Please tag and provide an example.

Comment: It's the exact same line of text....

Comment: @JvdV well, there is a full stop on the second... But a clear example would help here, I guess that the results should be in separate cells...

Comment: @SolarMike Well, the title does say "each word on a new line" and looking at the question in edit mode shows that the OP did press ENTER after each term, but because Stack Overflow markup needs two lines (except in code) it didn't show up correctly. I've edited to make it clearer. The question is still too broad, however...

Answer (score 0):

So, did this for a challenge, guaranteed to be better ways with vba, but wanted to make something with functions only...

With the target text in cell A1, then cell A2 has the following dragged down to A4:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(B1)-1)
```

In cell B1 dragged down to B4 is:

```
TRIM(IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)-1),A1))
```

See :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you. You'll just have to set it up the way you want to call it. but this code will take your string and break on spaces in to an array of undefined proportion. Then write each populated element in the array to the document.

```
Private Sub test()
  Dim MyLine As String
  Dim MyArray() As String
  Dim MyCounter As Integer

  MyLine = "Jacob Matt Ben Don"
  MyArray = Split(MyLine, " ")

  MyCounter = 0
  On Error GoTo Done
  While MyArray(MyCounter) > ""
    ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter Text:=MyArray(MyCounter) & Chr(11)
    MyCounter = MyCounter + 1
  Wend
Done:
End Sub
```